# No reconoce la conexión a la base de datos - Servidor

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo, object

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /hosting/distancia/1718/www/Clases/BD.php on line 207
```

La **línea 207** es una función de código **PHP** que funciona perfectamente en el **localhost**, en servidor local dentro de **xampp** en la carpeta **htdocs**.

La aplicación en LOCAL me funciona a las mil maravillas, pero en servidor no. Lo único que cambio del local al servidor es la conexión.

Este código o aplicación o proyecto lo paso a un servidor web y me dice el anterior error, yo creo que el error generado está en la errónea conexión a la base de datos.

```
static public function Conexion(){
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombre_bd", "nombre_user", "nombre_password");
        $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        return $con;
    }
```

**¿Por qué me da el error?**

Por si acaso incluyo **el error de la línea 207**, está en la función siguiente, en la misma linea del fetch().

```
static public function obtenerCabanasPorFecha($fi, $ff){
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $registro = $ejecucion->query("SELECT c.* FROM cabanas AS c WHERE c.idcabana NOT IN (SELECT idcabana FROM reservas WHERE ('$fi' >= check_in OR '$ff' >= check_out) AND ('$ff' <= check_in OR '$fi' <= check_out));");
        //Creamos un array de cabanas.
        $cabanas = array();
        //Mientras haya datos los guardamos...
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            $datos["imagenes"] = BD::obtenerImagenesCabana($datos["idcabana"]);
            $micabana = new Cabanas($datos);
            //array_push: añadir un elemento al final de un array.
            array_push($cabanas, $micabana);
        }
        return $cabanas;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que hay un error en la query y te regresa `false` como dice la [documentación en cuanto a `fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), y `false` no es un objeto por ende el error `Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object`, puedes decirle a PDO que te regrese los errores de esta forma

```
static public function Conexion(){
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombre_bd", "nombre_user", "nombre_password");
    $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $con;
}
```

Y atrapar los errores con un try catch

```
static public function obtenerCabanasPorFecha($fi, $ff){
    try {
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $registro = $ejecucion->query("SELECT c.* FROM cabanas AS c WHERE c.idcabana NOT IN (SELECT idcabana FROM reservas WHERE ('$fi' >= check_in OR '$ff' >= check_out) AND ('$ff' <= check_in OR '$fi' <= check_out));");
        //Creamos un array de cabanas.
        $cabanas = array();
        //Mientras haya datos los guardamos...
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            $datos["imagenes"] = BD::obtenerImagenesCabana($datos["idcabana"]);
            $micabana = new Cabanas($datos);
            //array_push: añadir un elemento al final de un array.
            array_push($cabanas, $micabana);
        }
        return $cabanas;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo  $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Si existe un error en la query te lanzara un error como este `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.cabanas' doesn't exist`

Otro punto que no tiene relación, me parece que de la forma que ejecutas la query estás expuesto a un ataque de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), podrías usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) entre otras cosas a considerar para hacer más segura tu aplicación

Comment: El problema que esa query y ese código de PHP en localhost sí funciona. No sé porque en esa función desde el servidor no funciona.

Comment: Pueden exisitir varios problemas con la query en el servidor, puede que la tabla no exista. Te recomiendo usar `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` y encapsular las llamadas dentro de un `try catch` para que puedas debuguear de una mejor manera

Comment: El problema que sólo me detecta ese fetch() en todo mi código, que contiene muchas funciones query de este tipo, la función de la que hablamos me funciona perfectamente en localhost, pero cuando cargo el fichero .php al servidor web me da este error. No lo comprendo...

Comment: Si entiendo tu problema, pero la única manera de saber que está mal con esa query en especifico es debugueando, te sugiero que la encapsules dentro de un try catch, mira mi respuesta editada para ver si te puede ser de ayuda

Comment: Voy a probar su edición en la respuesta... Me dice el error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' en la línea del "PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:ERRMODE_EXCEPTION".

Comment: Me suelta el siguiente error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '1718d0_osmar.cabanas' doesn't exist. El problema que si entro al phpmyadmin sí encuentro la tabla: "Servidor: localhost »Base de datos: 1718d0_osmar »Tabla: CABANAS"

Comment: Lo siento error de dedo :D 
Ahí está tu respuesta, la tabla no existe en la base de datos del servidor o la que estés usando y por eso te lanza ese error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71496/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-kacospro).